# count words of different classes separately in a text file

Tags: python, nlp

I have some text files in Persian. each file contains a lot of sentences, each in a new line. And in front of each sentence there is a tab, then a word, then a tab and then an English word. These English words in some files are 2, in some are 3, in some are 5 and in some other, are more or less. Actually, they show the sentences classes. I have to count each class's total words separately (just count the words of sentences not the words after them). For that I have to change the file to a list, so that I can achieve the sentences. Now the problem is that, how should I write the code that it returns each class's total words separately. Below is the sample sentences.

[image]

```
corpus = []
def CountWords (file):
    with open (file, encoding = "utf-8") as f1:
         for line in f1:
             t = line.strip().split("\t")
             corpus.append(t)
             for row in corpus:
                 if row[2] != row[2]:
```

Now I don't know how to continue. I appreciate a lot if someone can help. (I have no background in programming).

Comment: I'm not quite clear what problem you are facing, but you can use awesome [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) data structure to count elements in your files.

Comment: What do you mean by class's words? An example ?

Comment: for example, how many words are in "passion" class, how many words are in "salty" class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get you correctly then the next code might work. Please note, that I use Python 3.x.

```
from collections import Counter

counter = Counter()

with open(filename, encoding='utf-8') as f:
     for line in f:
         *persian_words, word_class = line.strip().split()
         counter[word_class] += len(persian_words) - 1

# Print the top 10 word classes with respective number of Persian words
for word_class, count in counter.most_common(10):
    print('{}\t{}'.format(word_class, count))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is what I wanted. But unfortunately, it doesn't return the right number of total words!

Comment: @suneye, what's the exact problem?

Comment: @suneye, are you able to give us more information? I check my code (the second version using `csv` module) and it works flawlessly.

Comment: @suneye, I see that you've uploaded an image to your question, but that doesn't help me. I need to get your plain text file.

Comment: I am trying the pastebin.

Comment: I copied the sentences there. But because it is in Persian, the first word after "tab" went to the start of the sentence. But the real file is as like as the picture above. I used Notepad++ for that. The code returns 10 for both the classes. But we can see that the words in each class is more than 10.

Comment: OK, you may upload the file to dropbox or something similar (i.e. not copy it to some textfield on a site, but upload your file).

Comment: Did you test the file?

Comment: @suneye, yes, it works. It prints "passion 34, salty 30". Though it seems you don't use tabs as a delimiter, so you don't need to specify it in `split` call. I fixed the first snippet - try it out.

Comment: Well, I just need the number of words of the sentences and not the words after them (after the "tabs"). look, after the sentences, there is one Persian word and one English word. The code doesn't count the English words and that's right but it counts the Persian words after the sentences. Can you please fix it in a way that it counts just the sentences. Thank you.

Comment: for "passion" it should be 29, and for "salty"  it should be 25.

Comment: I mean I don't want the English word and the Persian word before it, be in the counting. just the sentence.

Comment: @suneye, got it. It's an easy fix, if all your files have the structure you are talking about. Check it out now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to formulate your algorithm on paper then convert it to Python: I'm sure you'll find your solution by yourself.

If you encounter problems or errors, post your question here, we will be happy to help.

An advice:

- You can use ˋcsv` module to read your file. Look for some tutorial with this keyword.
- You can use ˋcollection.Counter` to count the number of occurrences of words. This can be useful.